# Line of code in while loop executing at wrong time

Tags: java, while-loop, io

Program code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.print("Welcome to my guessing game! "
            + "Would you like to play (Y/N)? ");
    yesOrNoAnswer = (char)System.in.read();

    if(yesOrNoAnswer == 'Y') {
        System.out.print("\n\nGuess the number (between 1 and 10): ");
        while(AnswerIsCorrect == false) {
            guess = System.in.read();

            if(guess == correctAnswer) {
                AnswerIsCorrect = true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("\nYou guessed wrong! Please try again: ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("You guessed correct! Congratulations!"
                + "\n\nPress any key to exit the program . . .");
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Welcome to my guessing game! Would you like to play (Y/N)? Y


Guess the number (between 1 and 10):
```

Actual output:

```
Welcome to my guessing game! Would you like to play (Y/N)? Y


Guess the number (between 1 and 10): 
You guessed wrong! Please try again:
```

When I input 'Y' at the first question (would you like to play) it proceeds to output, "Guess the number between 1 and 10: " This is a good output. However, before I can enter a number, it instantly outputs, "You guessed wrong! Please try again: "

How can I fix this code to achieve the expected output?

Comment: Debug your code.

Comment: are you generating the randome number between 1 and 10 for guess variable ?

Comment: @Lokesh Guess is a private static int variable, declared in the class, outside of the main method. It holds a value of 6, which is always the correct answer.

Comment: @Zachary post your full code? where you are reading correctAnswer from user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies at your usage of `System.in.read()`.

`System.in.read()` will read characters one by one and return them as `int`s. If I enter `1`, `System.in.read()` will return `49` because that's what the character `1` is encoded to.

The reason why it immediately prints that your guess is wrong without letting you type anything is that `System.in.read()` reads new line characters as well. If there is anything unread, it will read that, instead of asking for new input. There is a new line character after the `Y` you entered, so it reads that new line character.

You should instead use a `Scanner`:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // create a new scanner
    System.out.print("Welcome to my guessing game! "
        + "Would you like to play (Y/N)? ");
yesOrNoAnswer = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0); // reading the first character from the next line

if(yesOrNoAnswer == 'Y') {
    System.out.print("\n\nGuess the number (between 1 and 10): ");
    while(AnswerIsCorrect == false) {
        guess = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); // get an int from the next line

        if(guess == correctAnswer) {
            AnswerIsCorrect = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("\nYou guessed wrong! Please try again: ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("You guessed correct! Congratulations!"
            + "\n\nPress any key to exit the program . . .");
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

`Scanner.nextLine()` will return the input the user typed as a string and it ignores new line characters.